# While one of my deeplinks is working, the other one is not

Tags: android, android-deep-link

The deeplink I wrote this way works without any problems.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
    android:host="giris.example.com"
    android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

but this deeplink is not working. The application does not open.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:scheme="example.app" />
</intent-filter>
```

I read dozens of content on stackoverflow but could not find a solution.

Comment: Please explain what "not working" means -- how exactly are you testing and what you are seeing?

Comment: the application does not open

Comment: What is the exact deep link you're using that does not work?

Comment: example.app://test